# Opening a shell into a Java image

Tags: java, docker

I'm building a postgres+java container, and I'd like to open a shell into the java "service". That service exits immediately after starting, how can I do to open a shell into it?

I see it in `docker ps -a` but it has already exited.

The file I'm using is this .yaml with docker-compose

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:

      - datavolume:/var/lib/postgresql


  java:

    image: openjdk:8

volumes:

  datavolume:
```

Answer (score 2):

A Docker container generally runs a single process.  In the same way that just running a JVM without an application attached to it isn't really meaningful, running a Docker container with a JVM but no actual application added to it isn't that useful.

You should write a Dockerfile that adds your application's jar file to a base Java image; for instance

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY app.jar /
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

and then your `docker-compose.yml` file can have instructions to build and run this image

```
services:
  java:
    build: .
```

If you just want a shell in a copy of the image to poke around and see what's there, you can generally run

```
docker run --rm -it openjdk:8 sh
```

The [standard openjdk Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/86918ee28d383e7af63f535a2558040dce141099/8/jre/Dockerfile) doesn't explicitly declare any specific ENTRYPOINT or CMD so it will exit immediately when run.  (It probably inherits a default `/bin/sh`, but with no command to run, that will also exit immediately.)  You can declare some other `command:` in the Dockerfile to cause the "service" to not exit, but it's not really doing anything useful for you.